# Sending SMS in background automatically in android

Tags: android, sms, background-process

I have developed an app for local people in my place to use the app in an emergency case.

This app sends SMS automatically in the background every 15mins with their current location. This has been very useful for all the people in my place. Now after the new policy in effect for Send_SMS permission, I have been asked to remove send_sms permission. If I do that how do I send SMS automatically? The main idea of this App is that we don't need the internet.

Can someone throw some idea on how to send SMS without internet? This is the main feature for people to use my app?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** EMAIL FROM GOOGLE PLAY STORE: My team mate has filled the form wrongly and now they want me to change the permission but I understand we can still upload new version and fill the form correctly right?

EMAIL FROM GOOGLE:

Thank you for contacting the Google Play team. We have received the following information in the Permissions Declaration Form you submitted:

## 1: In one sentence, please describe the core functionality of your app.

Emergency App required to send location via SMS automatically to selected contact by the user.

## 2: What is the core functionality in your app requiring the Call Log and / or SMS permissions?

Default SMS [READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS], Device Automation [READ_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS, RECEIVE_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS]

## 3: Do any of the following disallowed use cases apply to your app’s core functionality request for Call Log or SMS permissions?

N/A

## 4: Do any of the following other use cases apply to your app’s core functionality request for Call Log or SMS permissions?

Physical safety or emergency alerts

## 5: Is your app’s use of Call Log or SMS permissions to provide functionality required by law or regulation?

No

## 6: Other

Emergency App to send users location to selected contacts. This is very critical functionality.

We reviewed your request and found that your app, SahAya - Emergency Alert, does not qualify for use of the requested permissions for the following reasons:

The declared functionality {Default SMS, Device Automation}  is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.
Please follow the steps below to submit an updated app.

Next steps

Read through the Permissions policy and review the Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups help article, which describes exceptions, invalid uses, and alternative implementation options.
Make appropriate changes to your app. Namely, remove the specified permissions from your app’s manifest or migrate to an available alternative. If you believe your use case should be allowed, please review the rejection reasons carefully, make the necessary changes to your app, and submit a new request via the Permissions Declaration Form.
Make sure that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.
Alternatively, you can choose to unpublish the app.

If you've reviewed the policy and have further questions, please reach out to our policy support team.

The Google Play Team

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303 10 line:
Applications that send SMS alerts in emergency situations I think Google should allow, write him.

Comment: @avp how to write to them?

Comment: @SanjanaNair How did you go with Google on this? Did you get an exception to use SMS_SMS from your emergency app.

Comment: Nope. It was rejected. And I have updated the app and filled the forum again. No response from them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get Google to approve of the permission for your app.

In the new [Use of SMS and Call Log Permission Groups](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303), there's an exception for:

> Physical safety / emergency alerts to send SMS
>
> Apps that send SMS alerts in emergency situations

If I didn't misunderstand your description of your app, it should fall within this exception, so make sure you explain yourself clearly to Google when you submit the permission request form.

Comment: Thanks! Please send what I received. One of my team members already posted some form and received an extension until March 9th. Please tell me what can be done. Thanks!